# Ubuntu 20.04 - LAN connects, but disconnects after 10 seconds

Tags: internet

I have the possibility to connect to the LAN of my University.
I have an external port/adapter, connected through USB3 to my computer, since my computer does not owns a LAN port. I connect the LAN, and everything works fine for about 10-15 seconds. Then the LAN disconnects. Can somebody help me understand what can be done to solve the issue? (P.S. the LAN worked about 1 year ago, with a different OS - I reinstalled the OS quite a while ago)

Comment: (1) Do you have Wi-Fi turned on at the same time as USB Ethernet? Have you tried turning off the Wi-Fi interface before connecting the cable? 

(2) Listyour usb devices and the status of network interfaces before connecting, during connection, and in fault state, i.e. 3 times:

`sudo lsusb`  `ip addr`

Compare the results.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.